# Azure MariaDB returns FeatureNotSupportedForEdition error but which feature?

Tags: azure, mariadb

I'm creating a MariaDB server on Azure via ARM template (using [this quickstart](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/quickstarts/microsoft.dbformariadb/managed-mariadb-with-vnet/azuredeploy.json) and specify `B_Gen5_1` (Basic) vm size. I get the following error:

> This feature is not available for the selected edition 'Basic'.

Which feature is referring in this error?

Answer (score 0):

I found [this question](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/185118/connect-to-basic-mysql-from-aks-nodejs-pod.html) on microsoft docs website and according to the answers the issue could be in Basic tiers not supporting virtual network endpoints. I'm not sure if that's correct